# .tag file not working in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, custom-tag

I have writted a tag file to display error messaage with attributes errormessage and errortype passed as attributes. But the same is not getting displayed in JSP.
Version used in xml is 2.4.

```
<%@ tag language="java" body-content="empty" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="errorType" type="java.lang.String" required="true"   %>
<%@ attribute name="errorMessage" type="java.lang.String" required="true" %>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${errorType == 'Error' && not empty errorMessage} ">
<div id="errorcontainer" style="width: 99%; display: block;" align="left">
<table border="0" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2">
<tbody><tr><td valign="top">
<img width="24" height="24" alt="Error" src="../gif/iconError.gif"/>
</td>
<td valign="middle">
<c:out value="${errorMessage }">
</c:out> 
</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
</c:when>
<c:when test="${errorType == 'Warning' && not empty errorMessage} ">
<div id="warningcontainer" style="width: 99%; display: block;" align="left">
<table border="0" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2">
<tbody><tr><td valign="top">
<img width="24" height="24" alt="Error" src="../gif/iconWarning.gif"/>  
</td>
<td valign="middle">
<c:out value="${errorMessage }">
</c:out> 
</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

I have used the below to include in JSPs

```
<%@ taglib prefix="custom" uri="/WEB-INF/tags"%> 
<custom:error errorMessage="<%=partsFormBean.getErrorMessage()%>" errorType="Error" />
```

I have placed error.tag under WEB-INF/tags.

Kindly provide me with a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get error message from Web-Server or IDE ?

Comment: No, i dont get any error message from Web Server

Comment: In first line you will be 'page' instant of 'tag' for language="java". test.

Comment: No, it isnt working.